# how to load different domain web page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to load another domain webpage in my website is it possible . for example i want to load http://www.cnbc.com/world/?region=world in my website. i have tried many solution jquery ajax  but none of them is working

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        url: "http://www.cnbc.com/world/?region=world",
        success: function(data) {
           $('#viewer').html(data);
        }
    }); </script>
 <div id="viewer"></div>
```

Comment: the above code is an example

Comment: Did you try simple google.com because CROS has to be supported what ever URL you are trying to access.

Comment: none of them means,searched for working code on google .tried many code .but not getting what i required

Comment: Why don't you use an `<iframe>` (knowing that the website you are trying to load does not deny` iframes` via `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header)?

Comment: Tried for an iframe but again the origin problem arises